# Input returning as undefined

Tags: javascript

Having trouble getting started tinkering with JS. Need to have a const be equal to the input field. Then onclick alert the value of the input so I can start working on the functions.

HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Number Checker</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, Javascript" />
    <meta name="description" content="Checks Number" />
    <meta name="author" content="Kaden Stewart" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/number-checker.css" />
    <script defer src="./Javascript/number-checker.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Number Checker!</h1>
   <br>

  </br>
   
    <form name="numberchecker" id="numcheck">
      <label for="number">Input a Number</label>
      <input type="number" id="number" name="number" />
      <button onclick="alert(num)">Check!</button> 
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
const num = document.getElementById("number").value;
```

Comment: `const num = document.getElementById("number").value;` will read the value once on page load. You want to read the value whenever you click the button.

Comment: Just assign the element to the const, leave off the `.value`:  `const num = document.getElementById("number")` then you can get the value from the varaible `alert(num.value)`

Answer (score 0):

Had to throw the line `document.getElementById("numberInput").value;` under a function like so.

```
function Check() {
  const num = document.getElementById("number").value;
}
```